# How to merge two vectors of objects by its id

Tags: c++, stdvector, multi-index, boost-multi-index

I have a function that tries to merge 2 vectors of objects by ids and save them to a table.

First I find the iterator (boost::multi_index)

```c
      details.modify(itr_to, _self, [&](auto &item) {
         auto update = combine_assets(item.assets, new_item.assets);
         item.assets= update;
      });
```

This function is supposed to merge the quantity of the asset for the same id.

```c
vector<item_asset> combine_assets(vector<item_asset> &existent_assets, const vector<item_asset> new_assets){
   for (auto &new_asset : new_assets) {
      int index = has_asset(existent_assets, new_asset.type); 
      if (index == -1){
         logtotable("not found");
         existent_assets.push_back(new_asset);
      } else {
         logtotable("found");
         existent_assets[index].quantity += new_asset.quantity;
      }
   }
   return existent_assets;
}
```

Finally this function finds is the assets exists:

```c
int has_asset(const vector<item_asset> &existent_assets, const uint8_t type){
   auto it = find_if(existent_assets.begin(), existent_assets.end(), [&type](const item_asset& obj) {
      return obj.type == type;
   });

   if (it != existent_assets.end())
   {
      // found element. it is an iterator to the first matching element.
      // get the index
      auto index = std::distance(existent_assets.begin(), it);
      return index;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

I'm having 2 problems:
First, the function has_asset always returns -1 even if the asset already exists.
Second,  `existent_assets.push_back(new_asset);` always only add the new asset, for example, if I have an asset type: 1 with quantity: 10 and send a new asset type: 2 with quantity: 5 when I return `existent_assets` it has only the asset type: 2 quantity:5

Comment: Most likely, `existent_assets` is in fact empty at the beginning. This would explain both observations. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: ^^^ that. Also, not related, but is there some specific reason `combine_assets` takes the `new_assets` container as const value param and not const reference param? E.g. what problem was solved by passing that as-value rather than const-reference?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I testes and existent_assets contains an asset as per explanation

Comment: @WhozCraig, I don't think so because the new_asset is the one showing in the end, for some reason existent_assets looks empty (even tho is definitely not)

Comment: Well, show the code that confirms that. To the extent there is a problem, it lies somewhere in the code not shown.

Comment: Note the **not related** in my prior comment. All I asked was why you passed `new_assets` by value rather than by reference. I never claimed it was a silver bullet; just wanted to know what drove you to do it.

Comment: @Icaro *First, the function has_asset always returns -1 even if the asset already exists.* -- That can't be the case, unless your compiler/linker that built your program is severely broken.  Otherwise, the compiler is not lying -- the asset you are searching for isn't there.

Comment: Thank @PaulMcKenzie, I can see on the table the asset type 1 before I call the function and after I call the asset type 1 is gone and the asset type 2 is in  its place, it is hard to debug as it is an EOS contract